# Certain Properties about Weierstrass polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-calculus

In my Real Analysis class we learned about the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem, which is more common known as the Weierstrass Approximation theorem saying that you can approximate anything continuous on the interval(or you can extend it to a general Topological space) with a sequence of polynomials, $(p_n)$ that goes to the function uniformly. So my question is this: Are all the terms in the sequence of $(p_n)$ is 0 when evaluated at 0? If yes, what is a way to prove it? Thanks

Comment: If $f(0)=0$ then you can impose this requirement, though the ability to do that doesn't follow from the basic version of the theorem (only the more abstract generalization). But in general no.

Comment: So if I require $f(0)=0$ what would be a sketch of the prove to claim that the polynomials are evaluated 0 at 0.

Comment: Just replace $(p_n(x))$ by $(p_n(x)-p_n(0))$.

Comment: Yeah you can prove it "by hand" instead of using any more powerful theorem than the basic version of Weierstrass. In more detail, given $p_n$ going to $f$ uniformly, $\| (p_n(x)-p_n(0))-f(x) \| \leq \| p_n(x) - f(x) \| + \| p_n(0) \|$, and $p_n(0) \to f(0)$ so $\| p_n(0) \| \to 0$. (Here most of these "$p_n(0)$" symbols are technically constant functions, not numbers.)